# Will changes to Java Options in the Tomcat Monitor App persist at runtime?

Tags: java, tomcat, runtime

I'm using the [Tomcat 7 Monitor Application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Tomcat_monitor_application) to add the following java options:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

-XX:HeapDumpPath=path
```

Once I hit the "Apply" button will these variables be updated at runtime, or do I need to restart the service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and `-XX:HeapDumpPath` are both [command line options](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbzrr), they take effect on JVM start only and therefore you'll need to restart your Tomcat for this configuration change to take effect.

However it is still possible to change both flags at runtime using jinfo or jconsole as indicated [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gdaxd).